# Prevent deletion of shared files in Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

Hey guys I'm wondering if it is possible using a script on Google Drive to prevent external users or regular account holders that you have shared documentation with from deleting that shared documentation but allowing them to retain edit access to the documentation.

There is no native functionality in Google Apps which can prevent editors of a shared file from deleting it. Can this be done with a script??

Comment: I don't think this has to be done in a script, there is a scope in Google Drive that allows read-write, but prevents deletion. See [Google Drive scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/scopes#google_drive_scopes). I think `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata` scope is what you are looking for. The description is "Allows read-write access to file metadata, but does not allow any access to read, download, write or upload file content. Does not support file creation, trashing or deletion. Also does not allow changing folders or sharing in order to prevent access escalation."

Comment: How does this work do you know? Does it directly manipulate the external users interface to prevent file deletion when they are accessing the files?